# $this keyword is not available in template of core/template block

Tags: magento-1.9, php, blocks, static-block

I want to execute some custom PHP code in a static CMS block. I want to do this by having a block of type core/template loading a template containing the PHP code. I have created the block and can do a "Hello, world" echo, however I can't access $this.

The code I use in the static CMS block to include the template with the PHP code is: `{{block type="core/template" template="module/template.phtml"}}`. core/template has been whitelisted.

Anyone has a clue why I can't use $this?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: This is the template content.

```
<?php
  $_product = Mage::registry('current_product')->getName();
  $this->helper('yotpo')->showWidget($this, $_product);
?>
<div id="yotpo-placeholder"></div>
```

EDIT: I ended up fixing this by declaring the block in my themes' local.xml, instead of using a static CMS block.

Comment: you added code in template.phtml ?
can you show your code here ?

Comment: theoretically you can use `$this` in templates. It is actually used everywhere in the core. `$this` references the block instance, in your case `Mage_Core_Block_Template`. Please add the template content so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: I've added the template content.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your code with below

```
{{block type="core/template" template="module/template.php"}}
```

to

```
{{block type="core/template" template="module/template.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it was a typo in my question. I was using phtml. Updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you. Replace `template.php` with `template.phtml`

**EDIT:**

you need change block type **core/template** to **module/model**.

Comment: Thanks, but it was a typo in my question. I was using phtml. Updated my question.

Comment: I have edited  my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to declare block class inside your block directives such as

```
{{block type="my/module" template="module/template.phtml"}}
```

instead of

```
{{block type="core/template" template="module/template.phtml"}}
```

In your case, `$this` is instance of `Mage_Core_Block_Template` and unable to call any methods from your block class.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should work with core/template as well. Maurius explains this as well in his comment on my post.

Answer (score 0):

you need to show your static block in Product page,
please make below changes

call static block in product page

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('your-static-block-id')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Modify your module/template.phtml

```
<?php
  $_product = Mage::registry('current_product');
  $this->helper('yotpo')->showWidget($this, $_product);
?>
<div id="yotpo-placeholder"></div>
```